# How to update many records with `dateAdd` in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

With a collection of

```
[
  {
    "user": "abc",
    "seconds": 1111,
    "time": ISODate("2020-05-05T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "user": "abc",
    "seconds": 2222,
    "time": ISODate("2020-05-05T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

I need to have another field, which adds the `seconds` to the `time` of individual record.

This seems to be possible with [dateAdd](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) which is added in version 5 (the database is version 5).

However, I am not able to achieve that with MongoDB Java driver `4.6.0`.

```
var alerts = db.getCollection("alerts");

alerts.updateMany(eq("user", user),
        set(new Field<>("time2",
                new Document("$dateAdd",
                        new Document("startDate", "$time")
                                .append("unit", "second")
                                .append("amount", "$seconds"))
        )));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB version 4.0, before $dateAdd of version 5.0, you can use `$toDate`:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      time: {
        $toDate: {
          $add: [
            {$toLong: "$time"},
            {$multiply: ["$seconds", 1000]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{multi: true})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bk1F5b_ioms)

Comment: Thanks, but I have difficulty translating it to Java, I receive "Object" of fixed values "$toDate" or "$dateAdd". Also, the database version is 5.